# I tried to install something with pip but i got this error

Tags: python, pip, lib

I'm trying to install TimeSide with pip but i got this error:

```
Collecting timeside
Downloading TimeSide-0.9.6.tar.gz (25.2 MB)
    ---------------------------------------- 25.2/25.2 MB 1.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [8 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\galax\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xvb9waev\timeside_35795cbfb69a4d58870e122e40910ad7\setup.py", line 93, in <module>
        install_requires=[get_dependencies('environment-pinned.yml')],
        File "C:\Users\galax\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xvb9waev\timeside_35795cbfb69a4d58870e122e40910ad7\setup.py", line 28, in get_dependencies
        environment = yaml.load(f)
    TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'
    [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I am using pip version 23.2.1 and python version 3.10.6.

Is there any way I can solve this problem?

I've been trying to install timeside with pip and pip3 since yesterday but I wasn't successful.

I will appreciate it if anyone here can help me

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip ...`?

Comment: yeah but i got the same error...

Comment: I think (and as per the error) the package itself has a flaw. And you'll have to wait for the devs to fix it. You can try it's previous versions tho

Comment: thanks, it worked! i could succesfully install timeside 0.0.3